# Unsupported compiler 'com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0' selected for architecture 'x86_64' on Xcode 7 Beta 2

Tags: compiler-errors, xcode7, xcode7-beta2

When I incorporated a popular OAuth2 library in iOS called [OAuth2Client](https://github.com/nxtbgthng/OAuth2Client) to my iOS app which is developed on Xcode 7 Beta 2 and then tried running the simulator, the following error occurred and the simulator didn't launch.

> Unsupported compiler 'com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0' selected for architecture 'x86_64'

What does this error mean? A lot of warnings (yellow triangle) followed with the error above (red octagon), such as:

> warning: no rule to process file '/Users/myUsername/myAppname/Pods/NXOAuth2Client/Sources/NSData+NXOAuth2.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture x86_64

How can I deal with the these errors and run the simulator properly? Or does CocoaPods only work on environments prior to Xcode 7 Beta?

#### UPDATE

Later I found that this occurs on any projects I create, not only on a project using CocoaPods. The only clue that occurs to me is that when I updated my iTunes to 12.2 today and then launched my Xcode, the dialog popped up, instructing to install new command-line tools.

#### UPDATE 2

I just upgrade to Xcode 7 Beta 3 but the error still got me annoyed...

Answer (score 5):

I met the same issue on Xcode 7 beta 4. I have tried to clean the project for several times but with no lucky. Unbelievably, restart Xcode saved my night. You can try this.

Comment: Just got this on Xcode 7.1 b2 - I wiped the Derived Data folder, tried to recompile, same error. Shut down Xcode, restarted it, error now gone!

Comment: Forgive me I overlooked your answer, but restarting Xcode is surely what I tried but it didn't resolve the issue. Just note that I already moved to GM and have no problems now. Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 3):

### Solution 1

Close Xcode, open terminal, before anything else, type: “defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode” (this addresses your Xcode settings) open Xcode and your project should work normally.

### Plan B

If that doesn't work try this to clear out your cache.  Save your files then put this in your terminal:
rm -rf Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/

### Potential causes

This bug can occur if you declared your pods with single quotes instead of double quotes or for some reason your pod files become corrupted (i.e.: working with p.lists, Google's p.list, firebase etc). I think what triggers the bug to break your code is during certain recompiling phases, for example: opening after unzipping the project, or opening the project after pulling it from GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

With the version (*X-code 8 beta 2*) I got the following error, because I tried to run it out of the downloads folder:

```
Unsupported compiler 'com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0' selected for architecture 'x86_64'
```

It helped to put it in the normal Program Folder!

Answer (score 1):

Angel's answer worked for me as well.  I too experienced this with 8b2, Moving the app to the Program folder instead running out of Downloads resolved it for me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! "Answers" like this should be posted in the comments section due to them not actually being a solution to this question.

Comment: Yes i agree, but i do not have 15 reputation yet and was not able to post a comment.  But i still wanted to share my response as it is helpful to the question.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just use the option of "build for running" this solved my error. I'm using Xcode 8.3 beta_2 on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.3

Answer (score 0):

In my case with XCode 9.0.1, I noticed that even after closing XCode, I had stuck processes running from an earlier version of XCode running:

```
$ ps aux | grep Xcode

dyoung           83871   0.0  0.0  2547420    708 s000  S    Tue11PM   0:00.19 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTInstrumentsFoundation.framework/Resources/DTServiceHub
dyoung           28009   0.0  0.0  2432804    796 s012  S+   10:24AM   0:00.00 grep Xcode
dyoung           27996   0.0  0.3  2869796  46088   ??  S    10:23AM   0:00.65 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Overlays/Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool --hostToRemoteFIFO /var/folders/k6/80v30vf13kdc8qd2rjtq35640000gn/T/ibtoold-27980/IB/BF1AA7D2-8B3F-4157-A447-6D700B84C105.HostToRemote --remoteToHostFIFO /var/folders/k6/80v30vf13kdc8qd2rjtq35640000gn/T/ibtoold-27980/IB/BF1AA7D2-8B3F-4157-A447-6D700B84C105.RemoteToHost
dyoung           27995   0.0  0.3  2869796  46060   ??  S    10:23AM   0:00.60 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Overlays/Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool --hostToRemoteFIFO /var/folders/k6/80v30vf13kdc8qd2rjtq35640000gn/T/ibtoold-27982/IB/2DC08948-3951-4E09-BBC0-CC4C27712A9C.HostToRemote --remoteToHostFIFO /var/folders/k6/80v30vf13kdc8qd2rjtq35640000gn/T/ibtoold-27982/IB/2DC08948-3951-4E09-BBC0-CC4C27712A9C.RemoteToHost
dyoung           27994   0.0  0.3  2869796  46076   ??  S    10:23AM   0:00.62 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Overlays/Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool --hostToRemoteFIFO /var/folders/k6/80v30vf13kdc8qd2rjtq35640000gn/T/ibtoold-27981/IB/DB22227E-FBD5-46B9-B90D-FF440135ABEC.HostToRemote --remoteToHostFIFO /var/folders/k6/80v30vf13kdc8qd2rjtq35640000gn/T/ibtoold-27981/IB/DB22227E-FBD5-46B9-B90D-FF440135ABEC.RemoteToHost
dyoung           27982   0.0  0.5  3830728  84644   ??  Ss   10:23AM   0:01.22 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtoold --sending-client-environment
dyoung           27981   0.0  0.5  3829860  84672   ??  Ss   10:23AM   0:01.20 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtoold --sending-client-environment
dyoung           27980   0.0  0.6  3842552  94472   ??  Ss   10:23AM   0:01.67 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtoold --sending-client-environment
```

One I manually killed all these processes then restarted XCode my compiler error magically went away.