# xcode command line build failed with com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cordova

XCode Version: Version 7.2 (7C68)
Building for PhoneGAP IOS
Commands used:

```
xcodebuild -project HelloCordova.xcodeproj -scheme HelloCordova -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator IDENTIFIER=com.kony.SyncApp build
```

It used to work well before upgrading Xcode after upgrading to 7.2 , i am facing this issue. And same wokring form XCODE UI
Problem with command line build

Error Info:

> fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
>   20 errors generated.

** BUILD FAILED **

```
The following build commands failed:
    ProcessPCH /Users/konysync/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloCordova-gyroiomjvclmgtfewwtckeoypgfd/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/CordovaLib_Prefix-almeazhzuslzcvewimbluxlrnwby/CordovaLib_Prefix.pch.pch CordovaLib_Prefix.pch normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    ProcessPCH /Users/konysync/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloCordova-gyroiomjvclmgtfewwtckeoypgfd/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/CordovaLib_Prefix-bvlrmrstkahcccfcihrhcdumeenk/CordovaLib_Prefix.pch.pch CordovaLib_Prefix.pch normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
```

### (2 failures)

found some links , but those links did not help.
[Apple LLVM Compiler 3.1 error clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457510/apple-llvm-compiler-3-1-error-clang) 
[Unsupported compiler 'com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0' selected for architecture 'x86_64' on Xcode 7 Beta 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152170/unsupported-compiler-com-apple-compilers-llvm-clang-1-0-selected-for-architect)

Comment: What are the actual errors? The "fatal error: too many errors emitted, ..." comes after the detailed error messages.  We need those details.

Comment: Not able to add logs here. Logs shared in below link, please check    http://pastebin.com/eXgaLRy4

Comment: Well here we are `#error architecture not supported`.  Do you understand what that means?

Comment: No,  i didnt
is it 16 bit or 32 bit

Comment: Well that's just the bitsize.  These days the architecures are `armv7`, `arm64`, `x86` and `x86_64`.  So that's ARM CPUs (devices) and Intel CPUs (simulators).  Looks like you are using the wrong architecture which could have happened when upgrading to Xcode 7.2   You'll need to check the supported architectures in the project build settings.

Comment: Any luck with this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clear the cache of pod with

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
pod deintegrate
pod setup
```

Change flipper version in pod file:

> use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5' })

And delete the project's Pods directory. The location of it is project directory > ios > Pods.
Then in the project directory > ios location, install pod with pod install
And

```
react-native run-ios
```

in project directory.

Comment: I  encountered the same error and I only removed all spaces in the path of the project and then every thing works fine

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug introduced in Xcode 7.2 (and still not fixed as of 7.2.1), see https://openradar.appspot.com/23857648 It seems that `xcodebuild` is not setting correctly the `ARCH` and `PLATFORM_NAME` variables when invoked with `-sdk iphonesimulator`.

There are two known workarounds at the moment, both involve passing extra flags to `xcodebuild`:

1) Pass the `-destination` flag, eg:

```
xcodebuild [...] -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6'
```

2) Override the `PLATFORM` variable, eg:

```
xcodebuild [...] -sdk iphonesimulator PLATFORM_NAME=iphonesimulator
```

Comment: ```-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6'``` works for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this error after upgrading to React Native 0.68.x
AppDelegate.m changed to AppDelegate.mm

1. You have to do this: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/841#issuecomment-636297029 open the project in XCode, then navigate to Build Phases, in Compile Sources remove the AppDelegate.m file and add AppDelegate.mm instead.
2. If it is not already renamed: Open XCode, rename AppDelegate.m to AppDelegate.mm in the Project Navigator

Answer (score -3):

i have tried to resolve this error many times and follows multiple steps of every one but not worked for me after that i deleted my build folder from project ios directory like react-native-project>ios>Build folder
it worked for me.