# React Native Azure Mobile build failing

Tags: react-native, xcode8, azure-mobile-services

I'm running with RN 40 and [RN Fetch Blob 0.10.2-beta.6](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob), and I can build the app for iOS without a problem on Mac. I have troubles when I want to build it with [Azure Mobile](https://mobile.azure.com).

The build fails saying:

> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed: CompileC
>   /Users/ci/agent/vstsagent/_work/1/output/build/build.obj/RNFetchBlob.build/Release-iphoneos/RNFetchBlob.build/Objects-normal/armv7/RNFetchBlobFS.o
>   RNFetchBlobFS.m normal armv7 objective-c
>   com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (1 failure)

If you have any suggestions how to debug this, or you are familiar with the error let me kmow.

Comment: Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125494/xcode-command-line-build-failed-with-com-apple-compilers-llvm-clang-1-0-compiler

Comment: Azure Mobile doesn't support React Native at this time.  It doesn't help your build failure issue (which is likely something else), but fixing that also won't help you.

Comment: What do you mean by this time? It worked like a charm before I installed
https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob

I followed these steps for the setup:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lfqZ8Uy2p3U&feature=youtu.be