# React Native Build Failed On IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, apple-m1

I am facing the below issue while running the command `npx react-native run-ios` in my Mac Os Monterey machine. Could anybody please help me with this?

```
** BUILD FAILED **
     
    The following build commands failed:
            CompileC /Users/prashanth/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-akpvurjcnemajucrerqjfkzzxnng/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTTurboModuleManager.o /Users/prashanth/Documents/REPO/app/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/turbomodule/core/platform/ios/RCTTurboModuleManager.mm normal x86_64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'ReactCommon' from project 'Pods')
    (1 failure)
```

I have the following piece of lines in the Pod file

`platform :ios, '9.0'`

`pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"`

Version of
**Node: 15.14.0,
React Native: 0.62.2,
Xcode: 13.4.1**

Thank you!

Comment: facing the same issue, please help!

Comment: Have you tired [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125494/xcode-command-line-build-failed-with-com-apple-compilers-llvm-clang-1-0-compiler)?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS Folder go to `Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/project.pbxproj`

Change all the `'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 11.0`' to `'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 12.4'`. save and run.

Note: every time you pod install, it will change, so you have to do it again. If there is a better approach please do mention it.