# react-native-firebase/app ios installation Error

Tags: react-native

after installing react-native frebase/app it works well for android , but in case of ios ...use of cd ios && pod install ..then pod is not installed ...follow the official documentation Altering CocoaPods to use frameworks
Beginning with firebase-ios-sdk v9+ (react-native-firebase v15+) you must tell CocoaPods to use frameworks.

Open the file ./ios/Podfile and add this line inside your targets:

use_frameworks!
To use Static Frameworks on iOS, you also need to manually enable this for the project with the following global to the top of your /ios/Podfile file:

$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true...
is it same folder ./ios/podfile and /ios/podfile ?
then also not installed the pod and then use of
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
use_modular_headers!
at the top of the pod file
and finally pod is installed but when build using npx react-native run-ios and then give a long error
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

2022-07-05 16:47:46.163 xcodebuild[11109:198292] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-07-05 16:47:46.163 xcodebuild[11109:198292] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/arindam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoChat-cttmfseavejzhadnawolzvwrzelz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsi.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/JSIDynamic.o /Users/arindam/Documents/test_projects/DemoChat/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi/jsi/JSIDynamic.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'React-jsi' from project 'Pods')
CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'YogaKit' from project 'Pods')
(2 failures)
please help i am new to react native...how to solve the issue...

Answer (score 1):

follow this.
[xcode command line build failed with com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125494/xcode-command-line-build-failed-with-com-apple-compilers-llvm-clang-1-0-compiler)

if above doesnt work, downgrade firebase version.
ie. package.json
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.9.0", // version 12 works great for me, but i get your error when i run version 15.

Comment: 12.9.0 version worked well , but when used react-native-firebase/messaging during pod install it should warn  NPM package '@react-native-firebase/messaging' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v15.1.1 but found v12.9.0, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.  ..and also for installing npm i @react-native-community/push-notification-ios or react-native-pushnotification for android ...please provide me the version ...as app should not crash for both the platform ...thanks ...

Comment: and my current project react-native versions are -0.68.2, 0.69.0 and 0.69.1..please help ..

Comment: it will crash during run time please inform compatible version with react-native firebase/app@12.9.0 of react-native-firebase-messaging,react-native-pushnotification, react-native-community-pushnotification/ios... not to crash with it..please

Comment: @React_Coder hi how did you solve it?

Comment: @React_Coder
Use version 12.9.0 for react-native-firebase/messaging as well and see if it works?

Comment: did you fix this? Getting same error.